# Facebook PHP SDK $facebook->getSignedRequest() Get User ID and Name. (Page Tab)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

**Facebook Page Tab Problem**

Well, I don't know how to say this, I want to retrieve the user's id and user's name on the page tab of facebook.

[image]

Then when you clicked the Application where the arrow points it should look like this.

[image]

I don't get it why the **Page Admin and Page Like is 1** it should output the ID of the users right? and why the **UserID is 0**? I logged on and I already liked the page

Then I wanted to retrieve the user's name and user's id "**to the user**" who will use this page tab app thing.

Here is my code for that.

```
if(!@include("../sdk/facebook.php")) throw new Exception("Failed to include 'facebook.php'");
$app_id = "xxx"; // Your application id
$app_secret = "xxx"; // Your application secret
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
$signedrequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$fbp_id = $signedrequest["page"]["id"]; //Facebook Fan Page ID
echo $is_admin = $signedrequest["page"]["admin"]; echo " Page Admin <br>";
echo $is_liked = $signedrequest["page"]["liked"]; echo " Page Liked<br>";
echo $uid=$facebook->getUser(); echo " User ID<br>";
```

Well I can retrieve the Fan Page ID, using the **$fbp_id** still, I can't retrieve the user's id **it only outputs 0**. How can I retrieve it? Any solution for this?

Would be glad if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all You must take a permission from your user to get his/her data. There are two ways you can do that the best way will be

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
 array(
 'redirect_uri' => $your_page_tab_url,
 'scope'  => 'email'
      )
```

After getting this url check if the user_id is 0 than redirect him to

```
<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>
```

but one more thing this is for the new PHP sdk so you will have to update the one you have