# Facebook php-sdk not able to get user id (i get 0) no matter what

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, userid

i really need some help over this one..

i m trying like over here [Facebook PHP SDK $facebook->getSignedRequest() Get User ID and Name. (Page Tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930648/facebook-php-sdk-facebook-getsignedrequest-get-user-id-and-name-page-tab) to create an app that is linked with a facebook page..so far so good..
the problem is that i cannot retrieve user id, no matter what, using php-sdk..

i ve tried also this fix, https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/ but it didn't make any difference

```
require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'myappid',
  'secret' => 'mysecretid',
));

$theRequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$user = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($user);
```

no matter what i ve tried i haven't been able to retrieve the user id..

i tried the link Paul suggested

with the following code

```
if ($_REQUEST) {
  $signed_request = $_REQUEST['signed_request'];
} else {
  echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
}

function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$data = parse_signed_request($signed_request);
var_dump($data);
```

i got a "NULL" as response.. :S

second edit.. i got this code

$information=parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret);
$oauth_token=$information["oauth_token"];

var_dump($information);
var_dump($oauth_token);

```
 $app_id = "myappid";
 $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/app_namespace";
 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=read_stream, friends_likes";

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($oauth_token)) {echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url .    "'</script>");}
```

in this way, i manage to get auth dialog, but in the redirect i get a message of misconfigured app..if i reenter the app, then i access all necessary info..token etc..
so if i find a solution why on the redirect i get misconfigured app, i guess i sort of solved my problem?

Comment: Did user authorize your Application?

Comment: i m using it currently on my own, as a developer, so i guess i m authorised by default?

Comment: I don't know if you've read this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/

But for a page app you have to : Register the app on your page, only try to decode the signed_request at the load of the page (basicly, just after clicking on the icon on the page to acces to your page app)

Comment: i hadn't actually read of this, but i still get a null...i ll provide the code with an edit on my first post..

Comment: @nikolas You aren't authorized by default

Answer (score 1):

i don't know who may find usefull this or not..
i think it would be a good idea, if facebook, suggested the discrete instances where each sdk is better applicable..
after spending quite few hours on the php sdk integrating with facebook app on a page tab, so, the app on facebook was out of question, i ended up that the javascritp sdk would serve my purpose better, since, 
a) it doesn't redirect the user, from my page to authenticate
b) it doesn't require app to be existing as a facebook app as well, (in my case i wanted to be shown as a page tab)
c) it make a kind of overlay of all the content, bringing forward the auth dialog, and then returning to my page, roviding all usefull information..

copying the code from several fb sources this worked for me

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    //alert(uid);
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
             FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    });
            } else {
            }
            });
        } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
 });

 // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) doesn't give the `user_id` and `oauth_token` until and unless the user has logged into your app.It would just give basic information about the User within the `user` key which is a JSON object containing the locale string, country string and the age object.
So if you want to get the `user_id` implement [Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/) or for test case here you can do following

```
<?php
$params = array(
  'redirect_uri' => 'http://yourdomain.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
if(!$facebook->getUser()):
?>
<script>window.location.href = "<?php $loginUrl; ?>"</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: i use 
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
); and i get no auth no nothing...i cant understand what is going on..

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
var_dump($loginUrl);

Comment: @nikolas You need to redirect to login URL for the authentication to happen

Comment: i managed to get signed request, but no success with login..and user id.. :S

Comment: What are you getting in `$theRequest` ?

Comment: i m getting sth sort of this.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-canvas/ missing lots of parameters.. and i tried to get that script i finally get auth dialog, and on return i get misconfiguered app!!! :S is the php-sdk supposed to solve problems?? :(

Comment: You can authorize your application in an easy way by going over to [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), selecting your application from list of application on top right corner and pressing **Get Access Token**. Try this and then go to your **canvas** page app and check if you get the User Id or not? Also @nikolas .. I am taking it default that you are viewing the result on a canvas app within the Facebook and not on website. Am I correct?

Comment: you are correct, like i posted in the very first, i m doing it all this within page tab from facebook page..

Comment: Anvesh, i updated my first post with some more code..this is actually producing some result, but the problem is that when it redirects it gives me a misconfigured app..

Comment: By misconfigured app you mean? And are you getting any of the field mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/